# How do I reference variable in Jinja Ternary operation?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, conditional-operator

How do I reference a variable inside the ternary operation?

ex:
`shell: "{{some_conditon == "True" | ternary('/bin/mycommand -F some_str_var', '/bin/myOtherCmmand -S some_str_var') }}"`

Comment: It's a bad idea to use "True"/"False" as strings in a condition. There are internal conversions.

Comment: The condition must be closed in parenthesis `(some_conditon == "True")`. Otherwise, the function has precedence `"True" | ternary(...)` and evaluates to the first string. This string doesn't fit the value in *some_conditon* and the result is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the strings

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (some_str_var == 'True') | ternary('echo ' ~ some_str_var, 'echo False') }}"
```

---

You might want to put the options into a dictionary instead of the long *ternary* strings. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    some_str_var: "False"
    cmd:
      result1: "/bin/mycommand -F True"
      default: "/bin/mycommand -S {{ some_str_var }}"
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ cmd[some_condition]|default(cmd.default) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml -e some_condition=result1
...
  msg: /bin/mycommand -F True
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml -e some_condition=resultX
...
  msg: /bin/mycommand -S False
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question to more relate to my use case. Please have another look

Comment: There is no difference except the strings are longer. I added an example of how to solve it. Don't use "True"/"False" as strings in a condition. Open a new question if you have other problems.

Comment: I think I'll just break this into two separate task, the ternary operation doesn't seem to fit this use case. Thank you for your response.